# How to partition for a successfull boot with raid5 + lvm +encryption

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, raid, lvm

I have been trying to make this setup work for several days.

The system never boots... When I do a setup without the software raid I can get it to work.

How should I set up my system partition to be able to boot with either legacy Bios or UEFI?

Another mysterious thing is that I can not directly set up raid 5 with all my discs, I need to do a small partition in the beginning of every disk at first. If I do not do this, there will be one "raid" partition on every disc but no raid volume with 2/3 of the total amount of storage space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bios booting, you just need one raid partition on each disk, unless the disks are larger than 2 TiB, in which case you must use GPT instead of msdos partition tables.  In that cause you have to create a 1 MiB bios_grub partition on each disk you want to install grub to ( preferably all of them ).

For EFI, you need to use GPT no matter the size of the disk, and create an EFI system partition and mount it in /boot/grub/efi.

Comment: Under BIOS, a BIOS Boot Partition (with a parted flag of `bios_grub`) is recommended on all GPT disks, no matter the size; although GRUB can often make do without that partition, GRUB is less reliable without it. Under EFI, the usual mount point for the ESP is `/boot/efi`, not `/boot/grub/efi`.