# Ubuntu 14.04 Manual Hard Drive Partitioning Help Needed

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, encryption, raid

I'm in need of some assistance with manual partitioning from the Ubuntu 14.04 install GUI.

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I have a 60GB SSD as that I want all my OS files on (root, home, etc.), and then I have 3 2TB HDDs that I want to partition so I can later configure them into a raid5 array using MDADM.

I want my 60GB drive to be encrypted as well as my 3-drive raid array. What would be the easiest way of doing this? Should I use the default encryption for the SSD and encrypt my raid drives later on once I have the raid array configured? Do I encrypt the raid array or the 3 individual drives?

I'm new to the Ubuntu manual partitioning and don't quite understand how to assign mount points and how to size swap partitions. I've also had trouble with disk alignment in the past regarding the raid array disks. Any support at all would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone could link some tutorials or give me a quick walkthrough on partitioning with multiple drives it would be much appreciated.

Overview of request (for clarity):

```
Drive1 (SSD 60GB): Encrypted, Boot Drive (/, /home, etc.)

Drive2 (HDD 2TB): Disk1 Raid Array
Drive3 (HDD 2TB): Disk2 Raid Array
Drive4 (HDD 2TB): Disk3 Raid Array
Raid Array: Encrypted
```

Thanks a bunch askubuntu,

Comment: Consider breaking this question up into two separate questions. 1. How to encrypt the SSD. This question is answered already at: [How do I setup full disk encryption on an SSD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53872/how-do-i-set-up-full-disk-encryption-on-an-ssd) 2. How to setup an encrypted RAID5 array? For this, take a look at [How to partition for a successfull boot with RAID5 lvm encryption?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/444617/how-to-partition-for-a-successfull-boot-with-raid5-lvm-encryption)